# Django - Get next X entities from a table that were created before or after a given date?

Tags: python, django

I was reading this [blog](https://pganalyze.com/blog/pagination-django-postgres) on pagination, but I'm trying to do quick queries by create date time. So for example if I get a request and one of the parameters is a date time I want a quick way to get the next X posts created in order. The reason I can't use this blog post is because the table could be updated by the time the user tries to request older or newer posts as it gets updated quite frequently.

So in a simple toy example: If I have a list of dates `[1-01-2021, 1-05-2021, 1-06-2021]` and I already sent `1-01-2021` to the user and the user sends me that date and X=1 then it expects the next single date it should return `1-05-2021` and not return dates it already has.

How can I do this quickly and efficiently? I imagine it might be tricky, because I have to order my table first. I'd like to be to do this in 2 directions as in forward and backward in times. So if someone gives me a date to one endpoint will return the 10 posts that came after that and another endpoint if given a date it will return the X posts prior to that one. How can I do this efficiently and quickly?

The best solution I have so far is to set `db_index=True` for `created` then order by `created` then given a date by the user do something like

```
results = Post.objects.filter(created__lt=some_date)
```

this seems less than ideal though. If someone can suggest a faster method that'd be much appreciated!

Comment: That's exactly how you'd do it, yes.

Comment: @AKX there's nothing faster?

Comment: How do you know it's not fast?

Comment: If the table is very large like a million rows feels like the ordering operation could be quite slow

Comment: That's exactly what the index is for. Filter and sort operations on indexed columns are snappy. Also, a million rows is approximately nothing.

Comment: (e.g. here querying something just like this takes 0.4 milliseconds over a million rows: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=96de966c498eb9e23834642721b7ab38)

Answer (score 0):

To get the next and previous X entities around a given date, you'd want to make sure the field is indexed (as you already had done with `db_index=True`) and then do

```
n = 5
results_before = Post.objects.filter(created__lt=some_date).order_by("-created")[:n]
results_after = Post.objects.filter(created__gte=some_date).order_by("created")[:n]
```

and if you need to, concatenate the two results (remembering `results_before` is in chronologically reverse order as it comes from the database), or pass them forward as two lists, whatever makes sense.

Comment: should probably be `created__gt` not `created__gte` right? I don't want posts with the date given. Also if I have parallel instances updating this DB, will the create dates never be the same between two different entities?

Comment: The idea with `gte` for one of the two queries is that you'd get entities created on that exact datetime, if there are any.

Comment: I actually don't want posts with that date. I want the user to be able to send me the date of the most recent post they have and I should retrieve X posts created after that. So if when posts are created in the DB if it's not sequential if they can have the same create date this might not work.

Comment: Well, then just `created_gt` – your client needs to be smart enough not to deal with any duplicates it might get (probably by rejecting them by primary key).

Comment: what do you mean by client? You mean Django? I'm hoping even if there are parallel create requests on the DB. I assume it still processes them sequentially regardless so create_date should for the most part be unique.

Comment: it might be better to sort by date then get the uuid of the post to get posts before or after.

Comment: I assume this is for some sort of pagination thing based on "I want the user to be able to send me the date of the most recent post they have and I should retrieve X posts created after that.". If there is a case where there's an exact duplicate timestamp (however unlikely that is), the user's client software should be smart enough to not process duplicate posts they already have.

Comment: hmmm I think I'd prefer a solution that doesn't have that problem at all. So maybe passing the uuid of the post is better.

Comment: You would need orderable UUIDs then, e.g. https://github.com/valohai/ulid2 (disclosure: library written by me).

Comment: unfortunately I can't choose UUIDs my app is linked with AWS Cognito which sends me a a unique user UUID when someone registers. Maybe an easier solution is to get uuid. Get that post filter by date and remove that post from the list. This should be relatively quick as well.

Comment: I meant unique ULIDs for Posts, not users.

Comment: of course sorry it's early for me

Comment: does `order_by` and `uuid__gt` work with this?

Comment: Yes, if the IDs are naturally sortable (e.g. ULIDs).

Comment: similar to my comment before if parallel creates are done on the DB. Does this library handle that by still enforcing an ordered uuid?

Comment: Primary keys are always unique, so yes, that's handled.